# This Terminal Emulator is not functional because no 'bash' shell could be found- Aptana Studio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, terminal, aptana

I am getting following error while trying to open the terminal in Aptana Studio 3:
This Terminal Emulator is not functional because no 'bash' shell could be found.
Please correct the problem and restart the IDE.

Here is the error log::

```
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_ZW
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86
!ENTRY com.aptana.terminal 1 0 2013-09-27 10:27:00.979
!MESSAGE Starting terminal process failed.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Shell executable could not be found.
at com.aptana.core.ShellExecutable.getPath(ShellExecutable.java:113)
    at com.aptana.terminal.internal.configurations.WindowsMingwConfiguration.getCommandLine(WindowsMingwConfiguration.java:40)
    at com.aptana.terminal.internal.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.java:38)
    at com.aptana.terminal.connector.LocalTerminalConnector.startProcess(LocalTerminalConnector.java:220)
    at com.aptana.terminal.connector.LocalTerminalConnector.access$0(LocalTerminalConnector.java:208)
    at com.aptana.terminal.connector.LocalTerminalConnector$1.run(LocalTerminalConnector.java:102)

!SUBENTRY 1 com.aptana.core 4 0 2013-09-27 10:27:00.980
!MESSAGE Shell executable could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-09-27 10:37:11.181
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Errno::EINVAL) =::
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.replace(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1623)
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it? I tried uninstalling Aptana and then installed again but same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like bash isn't in your PATH variable. Go to `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Environment variables`, then edit PATH and add the path to where your bash executable is. You'll need to restart Aptana Studio after that.

Comment: For me, just adding the path to git.exe from within Aptana solved it. Go to `menu Window -> Preferences -> drop-down menu Team -> tag Git`. Solution lead from: https://blogs.pigrider.com/blogs/7

Comment: @Shiyaz Note: you need the git.exe in the */bin* folder. any other git.exe file won't work. For example, some also have a git.exe file in the cmd folder, but that won't work for this.